# TypeScript factory functions that return a generic

Tags: javascript, typescript

(Typescript 2.1.0/VS Code 1.3.0)

I have a `Request` class that looks like

```
export default class Request<T>{
  static name = "adf";
  private url:string;
  constructor(url:string){
    this.url = url;
  }

  list(){
    return new Promise<T[]>(resolve=>{
      request(this.url,function(err,data: T[]){
        resolve(data);
      })
    });
  }
  get(id:number){
    return new Promise<T>(resolve=>{
      request(this.url,function(err,data: T){
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to create a factory function like so:

```
const enum requestType{
  machine,
  part
}
export default function(type: requestType): Request<T>(T.endpoint){
  return new Request<Machine>(Machine.endpoint);
}
```

I get the error `cannot find name T`, and a complaint about using an implicit any.  What's the proper way to make a factory function that returns a generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a generic function then it needs to have the generic type decelration:
`function fn<GenericType>(....`

Based on your code, you function should look more like this:

```
function factory<T>(type: requestType): Request<T> {
    switch(type) {
        case requestType.machine:
            return new Request<T>(Machine.endpoint);

        case requestType.part:
            return new Request<T>(Part.endpoint);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
let request: Request<Machine> = factory(requestType.machine);
```

Comment: I tried to do `Request<Machine>` instead of `Request<T>`.  I guess if I put  constraint on T like `where T implements SomeInterface` it would work.  Either way +1

Comment: is there a way to do this without the switch?